# How to save content editable div as another HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to load in HTML from a file into the editable div, then on a button click. Save the edited html from the div as its own html file.

I have tried:

```
*var textConvert = $('#editor').html($('textarea').html().replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
```

However, this solution does not work. It created an object, but it was a huge mess. The Javascript loads the HTML file into the `div` fine as text. However, I want to be able to retrieve the html after the user edits the contents of the div.

**Code:**

```
<div class="center">
         <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
         <textarea name="ticketDesc" id="editorCopy" required="required" style="display:none;"></textarea>
</div> 



<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#select_section').change(function() {
            var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
            var value = $option.val();
            var text = $option.text();
            if(value == 1){
                $("#editor").load("1.html");
            }
            if(value == 2){
                $("#editor").load("2.html");
            }
            if(value == 3){
                $("#editor").load("3.html");
            }
            if(value == 4){
                $("#editor").load("4.html");
            }
         
            
        });
</script>
```

Comment: No idea what you want to do, but instead of all the divs simply `$("#editor").load(value + ".html");`

Answer (score 0):

I 'm a little confused about the purpose of the `textarea` in the context of your question. If you load the HTML into the `contenteditable` div, you can edit the contents there and then just save down the `innerHTML` of that same div.

```js
const d = document

d.querySelector('button').onclick = e => {
  const storedHTML = d.getElementById('t').innerHTML
  
  console.log(storedHTML)
}
```

```html
<div id="t" contenteditable>
  <h1>This is a header</h1>
  <p>This is paragraph copy</p>
</div>

<button>Export</button>
```

Comment: So I used your code and tweaked it to what I need. It gives me the result which is great, but it cuts the code off randomly at a given line. I am using IE and I am not sure if the browser just has a size limit or something for printing out the HTML text.

Comment: I have tried using Google Chrome but it does the same thing

Comment: You shouldn't be hitting the string character limit unless it's a massive page that you're dropping in there. If you can put together a more comprehensive example in a codepen or something I can take a look